# Text view in cell with automatic size

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, cell

I am using tableview for Chat ViewController.
I need size to fit textView.
Height and width. But i can't make it with both parameters.

This first time setting constrains and it look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wdg0U.png).
And this second time setting constrains and it look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYIuX.png).

This is code MyProfile Cell.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if messages[indexPath.row].image != nil {
        tableView.rowHeight = 200
        if !messages[indexPath.row].owner! {
            let cell = self.chatTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("chatImageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChatImageTableViewCell
            cell.imageV.image = messages[indexPath.row].image
            let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tappedAtImage(_:)))
            cell.imageV.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
            cell.imageV.userInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = self.chatTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("chatImageCellEnemy", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChatImageTableViewCell
            cell.imageV.image = messages[indexPath.row].image
            let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tappedAtImage(_:)))
            cell.imageV.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
            cell.imageV.userInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))
            return cell
        }
    } else if messages[indexPath.row].owner! {
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        let cell = self.chatTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mymessageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyChatTableViewCell
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))

        cell.textView.text = messages[indexPath.row].text!
        cell.textView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        cell.textView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.textView.textAlignment = .Right
        cell.textView.textColor = .whiteColor()
        cell.textView.sizeToFit()
        cell.textView.layoutIfNeeded()


        let unix = NSTimeInterval(messages[indexPath.row].unixDate!)
        let messageDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: unix!)
        cell.timeLabel.text = timeAgoSinceDate(messageDate, numericDates: true)

        return cell

    } else {
        let cell = self.chatTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("messageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChatTableViewCell
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))

        cell.textView.text = messages[indexPath.row].text!
        cell.textView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        cell.textView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.textView.textColor = .blackColor()
        cell.textView.sizeToFit()
        cell.textView.layoutIfNeeded()

        let unix = NSTimeInterval(messages[indexPath.row].unixDate!)
        let messageDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: unix!)
        cell.timeLabel.text = timeAgoSinceDate(messageDate, numericDates: true)

        return cell
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

Read this blog, fabulous answer is given there. Hope this helps you and if not let me then i will go with your code work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I did not understand exactly what I did wrong. Could you help me with the code?

Comment: What problem actually you are facing, the image you have added in your ques , right side of the image i see the output , it appears correct, but  your code needs far much correction or may be  it is your need so you add all stuff. for info what is `messages[]`.

Comment: messages is array of struct Message, so message is:
struct Message {
    var text: String?
    var unixDate: String?
    var status: Int?
    var owner: Bool?
    var id: String?
    var image: UIImage?
}

Comment: What and where you are facing the problem. I mean what your expecting output and what output you are getting. Please describe again in your question with multiple images.

Comment: So main problem is that I can't set automatically with and height. (Now only width or height)

Comment: Ok, give some comments in your code work, so that I can understand what you have done in each line. According to which I will check. And little bit describe what Component you are using like `UILabel` or any other.

Comment: I am using a 4 cells. 1 - A Text message by sender, 2 - A Text message by recipient, 3 - Image message by sender, 4 - Image message by recipient.

You can see this on screens. So I'm using a rotated tableview and rotated cells for chat. And that's all. All text in textview filling with array messages. It is struct array.